# Cannot get css to apply to Angular Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've been stuck on this for a while.

I created an Angular component called app-place-icon-avatar.

I would like the app-place-icon-avatar to be either 55px in height or 100% the height of the div.

I've tried a bunch of things.

Please see the screenshot for what I am referencing.

The html element shows 17px tall when I inspect it, but the css of 55px seems to be applied correctly.

I've tried applying ::host /deep/, ::host, applying a style directly to place-icon-avatar in the parent component's html.

The css seems to be being applied when I inspect it. It says height 100% on the right, but the actual app-place-icon-avatar is 17px no matter what I do.

I'm new to angular, and I'm sorry if I am missing something basic, but I've searched for a while and can't find anything that works.

The reason I would like to make this component a certain height, is that it is easier to center it. Since the image within the app-place-icon-avatar is 55px, but the app-place-icon-avatar itself is only 17px high, it makes it difficult to center it vertically. I would like to make it as simple as possible.

```
:host /deep/ {
  height: 50px;
}
```

I am expecting the app-place-icon-avatar to be either 55px or 100% in height. It is 17px no matter what I try.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/48p5o.jpg

Comment: can you try ::ng-deep  with !important

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't seem to be taking effect.

Comment: Are you using SASS or pure CSS?

Comment: Try changing the component display mode to either `block` or `flex`

Comment: Jojofoulk nailed it. Changing it to flex made the css start applying. Still not sure as to why it wasn't being applied before. I believe it was inline-block before. Thank you though Jojofoulk. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Jojofoulk gave me the answer, which was to change the displaymode to flex or block. That solved the issue.